# opening a cursor after some code

Tags: sql, cursor, db2

I have some Stored Procedure in DB2. Some lines of code (*INSERT*, *UPDATE* etc). After some operations I have IF condition that opening/not opening CURSOR. For some reason the CURSOR is not opened even if IF condition is TRUE. All the code before the CURSOR works fine. If I'll remove it, so the CURSOR will works fine. If I'll put the CURSOR in separate SP, it works fine (calling for another SP from this SP). But together for some reason it not works. I can't understand why. I need this code for the IF condition.

That's how it looks (only 1 row with INSERT left outside the CURSOR):

```
DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
SELECT s.KEY, s.CODE, s.PRODUCT, s.AMOUNT
FROM DB2ADMIN.SALES s, DB2ADMIN.PRODUCTS p
WHERE s.DATE_KEY = CDC AND s.PRODUCT_KEY = p.PRODUCT_KEY;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
SET EOF = 1;

  INSERT INTO DB2ADMIN.IA_BASE_SALES_TMP (SOME_FIELD) VALUES (SOME_VALUE);

   IF true THEN
      OPEN C1;
      WHILE EOF = 0 DO

        FETCH FROM C1 INTO SP_KEY, SP_CODE, SP_KEY, SP_PRODUCT, SP_AMOUNT;

        MERGE INTO DB2ADMIN.IA_BASE_SALES_TMP t
        USING (
              SELECT POS, p.KEY, s.TELLER, s.TYPE, s.AMOUNT, s.CDC
              FROM DB2ADMIN.COMMISSIONS s, DB2ADMIN.PRODUCTS p
              WHERE TELLER = SP_TELLER AND TYPE = SP_TYPE 
          ) e ON t.TELLER_KEY = e.TELLER_ID         
          WHEN matched          
         THEN UPDATE SET t.KEY = e.KEY, t.UPD = 0;

      END WHILE;
      CLOSE C1;

    END IF;
```

Comment: Cannot you put all the cursor inside the if statement? Also, in general, you can get rid of cursors and stick with relacional logic (needs a bit a effort but it pays in performance)

Comment: delcaring of cursors must be before the code. i tried :(   how can I get rid from cursors? I need to get several rows and loop though them.

Comment: Programmers do use cursors because they are used to think with imperative logic (from imperative languages like C, java, PHP, etc), Relational DBMS do use relational logic. Shame I don't the time now but I'm sure you can get rid of that cursor and just stick with selects, joins and maybe temporary tables

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jean.

Replacing the cursor with FOR loop and everything works OK.